# How to modify maximum RAM usage in vCenter 6.0

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-server, vmware-vcenter

I'm using VMware vCenter 6.0 on Windows server 2012 R2 and I'm looking for a way to decrease RAM usage of it. In previous vCenter versions there were options to change `# Maximum Java Heap Size` in `C:\Program Files\VMware\Infrastructure\Inventory Service\conf` but in this version those files aren't available. I only could find `C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\invsvc\wrapper\conf\wrapper.conf`in version 6 and the `WRAPPER.CONF` file didn't contain `# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)`. it's only for inventory service, I couldn't even find that file for tomcat server.

so my questions are

1. where can i find those files in vCenter ver 6.0?
2. Is there any alternative to modifying `WRAPPER.CONF` file for decreasing RAM usage?
3. which non-critical services of vCenter 6.0 can I disable in order to increase overall performance but yet be able to use basic features of Web client?

Comment: You should really be using the vSphere vCenter Server Appliance (Linux) these days...

Comment: Well there are many reasons like It's harder to manage a Linux server than Windows server 2012, at least for me, I can manage most parts of the OS by myself but in Linux I don't have enough knowledge, and I can't install VMware Horizon View Composer on the same server. There should be some ways to manage it in Windows server too. also the minimum requirement RAM for vCenter Server appliance is 8 GB but I read people could manage to decrease the RAM usage to 4 GB in vCenter 5.5, so its scalability is much higher. I need to do the same to vCenter v 6.0.

Comment: The whole point of the VCSA is that you don't HAVE to do anything with the linux side of things, zero - it just works as an appliance! It really does make sense to drop the Windows version (and the .net client) as soon as possible as they're 'going away' soon enough.

Comment: @Chopper3 VMware is dropping Windows server based version of vCenter? In your experience, VCSA has better RAM optimization than Windows vCenter?

Comment: A) Yes, they want to move away from all Windows-based services, and before v7 too, already the Windows version of vC with the built-in-DB is already less capable that VCSA (though that might actually be NDA sorry, I work closely with them) and B) I have to admit I've never compared them - even during VCIX-exam-prep - that's how unlikely I am to deal with the Windows version :) Most people don't care because their hosts have easily enough memory to make any tiny variation insignificant - are you very memory constrained? if so that's not exactly best-practice.

Comment: Also you might be interested in this article Will Lam wrote (http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2015/02/dynamic-memory-resizing-for-vcenter-server-6-0.html).

Comment: Thanks for the article. so as i said in vCenter 5 we could limit the RAM usage to 4GB but in ver 6 it's done automatically and the limit is 8GB. my system has 12 GB RAM so i can say it's not enough for both ESXI and vCenter. what I actually going to achieve for now on my system is to run a VM in ESXI 6 and work with it on a laptop using web client (browser) or from a remote place. I don't really need management features of vCenter. any suggestion?